# Debugging .vue component in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, vue.js

Is it possible to debug a .vue component in Chrome.
So far I only get orange marked source that chrome does not recordnize for debugging i.e. I can't inspect variables etc.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Orange marked source? Have you tried source maps?

Comment: this is great if you use VS code https://medium.com/@brockreece/how-i-stopped-using-console-log-when-debugging-vue-components-14e0f7aa280d

Comment: Tried the [Vue.js devtools extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd)?

Comment: @Phil: yes but I want to debug the source, the plug in does not help

Answer (score 5):

Yes of course it is possible.

---

First you need to make sure you are using a non-minified / non-production version of Vue.js  You can verify this by looking in development tools at the console output.  If your Vue version is a development version allowing for debuging you should see the following message in the console.

```
You are running Vue in development mode.
Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.
```

---

Secondly you need to install Vue.js Devtools plug in.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en

Note: if you are not using a web server, but simply loading local files in the browser "file://somefile.htm"  you need to go into the chrome extention and in the plug-in settings and allow the plug-in "Permission to access file URLs"

---

Third, you can turn on "source map"  Depending on your setup there are different ways to go about this.  If your project is just set up using the CLI then find your `config/index.js` file and make the `dev-tool` property is set to `devtool: 'source-map'`

If you are using Webpack or Laravel mix you can enable source maps with the `.sourceMaps()` method in the Webpack config file.  Other changes may be necessary as well.  https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/

Comment: I am using vue cli 3 and think it is already executed in development mode, but so far I can`t find a source map configuration.

Comment: @skribe I have the same problem i generate a project with vue cli 3 and I dont find a config/index.js or vue.config.js or something like this. Can you help me pls?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977685/debug-vue-cli-3-generated-app-from-visual-studio-code

Comment: Oh, and depending on how you generated your project you may not have a config file. In that case just create one. See here https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#global-cli-config