# Debug vue-cli 3 generated app from Visual Studio Code

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

I generated an app using vue-cli 3.0.0-rc.3

Now I want to debug it using Visual Studio Code (Debugger for Chrome) however I can't seem to find the option to turn on sourceMaps.

I set the breakpoint in VSCode but it is not hit. 
If I specify: "sourceMaps: true" in vue.config.js, I got an error "Invalid options in vue.config.js: "sourceMaps" is not allowed"

What option needs to be set for debugging to work?

Comment: Best way to debug with Vue for me in my last project was the Vue devtools extension for chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd

Comment: Also Vetur vscode extension very useful one https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur

Comment: @EmileCantero: yes, vetur and devtools are great I just started experimenting with them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Official cookbook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/debugging-in-vscode.html) these steps needs to be done:

vue.config.js file has to be edited and add:

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'source-map'
  }
}
```

then launch.json should look like this:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "vuejs: chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:8080",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
      "breakOnLoad": true,
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

After these steps breakpoints started to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, I also had to follow the steps in this post: [Visual Studio Code breakpoint appearing in wrong place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50765353/visual-studio-code-breakpoint-appearing-in-wrong-place)

In particular, setting the sourceMapPathOverrides property. Finally got my breakpoints to work in Visual Studio Code using Vue.js. :)