# How to debug Vue application with google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, vue.js, nuxt.js

I would like to step away from using console.log all the time and use the Chrome Developer Debug Tool more often.
I found this nice [How to stop using console.log() and start using your browser’s debugger](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/stopping-using-console-log-and-start-using-your-browsers-debugger-62bc893d93ff) about debugging in general (setting breakpoints, executing line by line etc.)

But when I tried to use this in real life – which means to use it in a vue (nuxt) application I am working on – I could not get it to work.

All my files are combined into more complex javascript files, which I cannot debug.

[image]

I then found this post:
[Debugging .vue component in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49892107/debugging-vue-component-in-chrome)
Which I thought would shed light onto this matter, but unfortunately I don't know what to do.

I added this:

```
configureWebpack: {
  devtool: 'source-map'
},
```

To my nuxt.config.js

But I would not see any sourcemaps of all my .js files in the debugger.
It would be nice if I could find all the js files for each vue component, for each store file, and for other utility files I wrote.
I am not sure if this is even possible, but I guess there must be a way to find my Javascript code within the debugger tool to actually debug it.
Or am I wrong?

Comment: What editor/IDE are you using? There's a dedicated post to debug Vue in VS Code:  https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/debugging-in-vscode.html

Comment: vue devtools chrome extension- extremely useful https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd

Comment: thanks @BennettDams and efrat. I already got vue devtools, but I want to dig deeper.. (or I am missing some functionality of those tools). I am using Atom. So no Visual Code. I already found that article, thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Nuxt.js defines **sourcemap** in build property from nuxt.config.js file:
Step 1:

```
 build: {
        extend (config, { isClient }) {
          // Extend only webpack config for client-bundle
          if (isClient) {
            config.devtool = '#source-map'
          }
        }
 }
```

Step 2: run npm command line again (nuxt will not apply code in nuxt.config.js unlike another page

```
npm run dev
```

Step 3: Open chrome , press ctrl + shift + I or press F12 to open source via : ///webpack ...

I found this in this official's url: https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#extend

Comment: I already found a solution to make it work. But your solution does not solve my problem, that now build times went through the sky...

Comment: @Merc Long ago you asked about sourcemap and now you still have a problem? Or are you talking about a slowness of hot reloading? Please clarify for readers, i just started nuxtjs and wondering about the same issue you asked in OP.

Comment: @bob I asked about source-maps. That's right. I should have marked the first solution as the solving one. (I did mention in the comments...) But as also stated above (I provided a link) It makes the build incredibly slow, so it is definitely no help for development, cause in the time waiting for the build is slowing me down more than source maps would help me to speed up my work... – so `TLDR; ` I still have no good way to debug my vue application!

Comment: No actually, I could not have marked the solution as the one that solves the thing, because I never tested. As I mentioned in my comment, I got it to work by myself, with `configureWebpack: { devtool: 'source-map' },`...

Answer (score 2):

Use below configuration in nuxt config file

```
    build: {
        filenames: {
          chunk: '[name].js'
        },
      extend(config, ctx) {
          const path = require('path');
          // Run ESLint on save
          if (ctx.isDev && ctx.isClient) {
            if (ctx.isDev && ctx.isClient) {
              config.devtool = '#source-map'
            }
          }
        }
}
```

Hope it will serve your purpose, and you can use **debugger** keyword into your javascript code for setting break point by your own intentionally, as well as you can set break point into browser .

Comment: Actually I got it to work some time ago with `configureWebpack: { devtool: 'source-map' },` But the problem was that the build time was going up so much, that I could not work with it anymore. It would be just to slow. So I am faster logging things and have a fast build time instead of having nice debugtools but I have to wait for the smallest change to appear on screen... (any thoughts on that?)
But thanks anyway.

Comment: Which is the code I posted in my initial question . I cant' recall why it did not work in the first place. Anyway it's way too slow...

Comment: build process slow does not matter, because Nuxt has hot reload mechanism, so after run any changes into code will load automatically, and it is will not make any slowness in production mode, so no need to worry

Comment: Well only it does. I tried and when I make small changes to some scss files it needs a lot more time until it reloads my page... Also this is stated here:
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#devtool
`source-maps` - `slow`

Answer (score 2):

For those of you who are trying to debug nuxt and are using typescript. Here are the vs code configs for using nuxt-ts.

```
// .vscode/launch.json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "client: chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:{ADD_YOUR_APP_PORT_HERE}",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "server: nuxt",
      "args": ["dev"],
      "osx": {
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/nuxt-ts"
      },
      "linux": {
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/nuxt-ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "compounds": [
    {
      "name": "fullstack: nuxt",
      "configurations": ["server: nuxt", "client: chrome"]
    }
  ]
}
```

You also will need to enable source maps like this:

```
// nuxt.config.ts
    extend (config: any, ctx: any) {
        if (ctx.isDev) {
          config.devtool = ctx.isClient ? 'source-map' : 'inline-source-map'
        }
    }
```

I wrote a detailed tutorial on my blog : https://mansour.blog/enable-vs-code-debugger-for-nuxt-and-typescript